# calling library functions from different language

Tags: libraries, system-programming

As we know libraries are precompiled codes, so we do not need to compile them. Can we call library functions of one language from a different language?

Comment: Of course not.  How would you even go about this?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad for UL imho, but look for terms like 'language bindings' or 'wrappers' e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface or see this SO question [What is a language binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865/what-is-a-language-binding)